# bypassSecurityTrustHtml disables anchor tag while displaying html using [innerHtml]

Tags: angular, angular-dom-sanitizer

I am using Angular 10. I have a scenario to get html string (value returned by rich text editor) and display it in my Application (using `innerHtml`). I'll be getting all kinds of styles, like background color, font-color, highlight text, hyperlinks etc.

I am using `bypassSecurityTrustHtml` via pipes (code is below) so that `<styles>` tags will be considered.

```
// sanitizeHtml.pipe.ts

@Pipe({ name: 'keepHtml', pure: false })
export class SanitizeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
  }

  transform(content) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(content);
  }
}
```

Now the problem is that when I get hyperlink texts `<a href="http://www.someurl.com> click here </a>`, these anchor links are not working. So, when I click on the link, it doesn't open the **href** link.

I've seen solutions like using `bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl`. But I cannot use it as I won't be able to parse the url alone from the html content.

I also tried to use both the functions like below as suggested in other SO questions but it doesn't help either..

`[innerHtml]="myHtmlContent | keepHtml | keepUrl"`

`[innerHtml]="myHtmlContent | keepUrl | keepHtml" // tried to reorder the pipe still didn't work`

Is there a way to make the anchor tag's href links work while using bypassSecurityTrustHtml function?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After doing some debugging, I just found that we **don't need to** sanitize url seperately which is inside html string.

If you are using pipe with `bypassSecurityTrustHtml` and it doesn't work properly with the anchor tag links, then you would have probably done the same mistake which I did.

---

**Solution**

Just remove `pure: false` from `@Pipe({ name: 'keepHtml', pure: false })`. By doing so, your pipe will became pure pipe (as `pure: true` is default value)

Pure pipes will be executed only if it detects a change in the value or parameters passed to the pipe where as impure pipes will be called for every change detection cycle.